# R inline markdown

Tags: r, pdf, markdown, rstudio, r-markdown

I’m using R Markdown in RStudio to create a report that mixes Markdown and R output. I know how to use inline R expressions in the Markdown, but I’m wondering how to do the converse, i.e., use Markdown within the R code. I want to loop through a series of calculations and get Markdown headings for each one. I want headings for formatting purposes (e.g., bold titles etc) and also to be able to specify (sub)sections in the resulting PDF (which is a nice feature of the way RMarkdown handles # and ## etc).

I know I can do the following:

````
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
---

#Section 1

```{r, echo=FALSE}
print(1+1)
```

#Section 2

```{r, echo=FALSE}
print(2+2)
```

#Section 3

```{r, echo=FALSE}
print(3+3)
```
````

Which gives something looking (roughly) like this:

## Section 1

`## [1] 2`

## Section 2

`## [1] 4`

## Section 3

`## [1] 6`

Is it possible to achieve the same output using something along the lines of this:

````
---
title: "test2"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
for (i in 1:3)
{
  print(paste("#Section",i))
  print(i+i)
}
```
````

Comment: `cat(paste("# section",i,"\n"))` should do if you set the chunk option `results="asis"`

Comment: Thanks scoa, that output is slightly nicer, but doesn't achieve what I want: the # is interpreted as a character, and printed, rather than interpreted as a Markdown tag to create a header.

Comment: Sorry, you should add two "\n" in paste : `cat(paste("# section",i,"\n\n"))`. Markdown headers need an empty line beforehand. Same thing for print(i+i) : `cat(paste(i+i,"\n\n"))` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks @scoa. Still no luck, I'm afraid. I tried `cat(paste("\n","# section",i,"\n\n"))` to ensure an empty line beforehand, but I get an output of `# section 1` rather than **section 1**.

Comment: even with  `results="asis"` as a chunk option? `{r, echo=FALSE,results="asis"}` ? that would be weird, it works on my machine

Comment: @scoa Yes, I have  `results="asis"` as a chunk option. But you get something that looks like my example formatted output? Do you have your .Rmd set to `output: pdf_document`?

Comment: yes, same output in pdf. Then I don't see why it doesn't work... Maybe try updating knitr and rmarkdown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @scoa pointed out, you have to set the chunk option `results='asis'`. You should also place two `\n` both before and after your header.

````
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
for (i in 1:3) {
  cat(paste0("\n\n# Section", i, "\n\n"))
  print(i+i)
  cat("\n\n\\newpage")
}
```
````

Comment: Thanks Christoph. After some playing about, I figured out why it wasn't working for me -- I tabbed my code block within RStudio so that it would show as a code block when pasted into StackOverflow. That interfered with the reading of the chunk option. So, scoa was correct -- the critical thing was the inclusion of `results='asis'`. I'm not sure what the etiquette is here, but I feel that @scoa should get the credit -- if (s)he adds the answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: Sure thing, and I did not mean to nick his answer. Let him write an answer and mark it as such (though you might mark my answer as useful for the time being). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As a more general answer, it could be useful to a look at the [markdownreports](https://markdownreports.github.io/) package that parses markdown code (and output) from your R variables.